# Can not open password-protected ppt with libre office 3.5

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, libreoffice

When I am trying to open password-protected ppt with libre office 3.5 in Ubuntu 12.04,it gives me a message says "Read-Error. loading of password-encrypted microsoft powerpoint is not supported."So is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Open it with powerpoint and save it without password encryption...

Comment: Sorry,I can not understand.Could you do more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The ppt you are trying to open in Libre is password protected in MS office. Libre Office cannot open such password protected files. So, for this, Install **Wine Windows Program Loader** software from Ubuntu software center and then open yout .ppt with it.